# How to get the calender info of the candidate inside an orgainzation with google business app using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am using the gogole html web app scridpt, from where I have to the input in index.html and pass that info as form object to code.gs file where it uses the start time and end time and some user ids of the candidates in the abc.com organization.

Now I have to find in the calender the free time of all the email id used.

```
var user1_Cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('user1@abc.com');
var user2_Cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('user2@abc.com');
```

Finding all the free and busy during date1 and date2

**script.html**

```
<div>
<form id="myform">
<input type="user1" name="user1" id="user1" placeholder="Enter your id">
<br>
<input type="user2" name="user2" id="user2" placeholder="Enter your id">
<br>
 <input type="start" name="start" id="start" placeholder="start">
<br>
<input type="end" name="end" id="end" placeholder="end">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="myform_val">
</form>

</div>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css').getContent(); ?>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
      <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      $( "#myform" ).submit(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
          console.log(ret);
        }).addEmail(this); //"this" is the form element
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
   try{
      var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('Web App').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);

    }catch(error){    
      var errorSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('errorsheet_id_here').getSheetByName('errors');
      var cell = errorSheet.getRange('A1').offset(errorSheet.getLastRow(),0);
      cell.setValue(new Date() + " function doGet: " + error);

   }
   return html;
}

function addEmail(form){
  try{    
     // here we can use the form.user1, form.user2, form.start, form.end 
     var user1_Cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(form.user1);
     var user2_Cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(form.user2);
     /// using these two candidate info and between start and end time we have to find all the free time and the put into the output_array and that can be returned back to index.html

 Logger.log(user1_cal.getName()); 
 var today = new Date();
 Logger.log(user1_cal.getEventsForDay(today));
 var events = user1_cal.getEventsForDay(today);
 Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);
 // I am getting the number of events but want the actual start and end time.
    var myval = JSON.stringify(output_array);
    return myval;
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    var errorSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_id').getSheetByName('errors');
    var cell = errorSheet.getRange('A1').offset(errorSheet.getLastRow(),0);
    cell.setValue(new Date() + " and error is : " + error);
  }
 }
```

Question: How to get the user calender free busy details 
NOTE : In google calender business app the setting is as 
[image]

Comment: I think you need to query freebusy for that info https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query

Comment: that api is using third party code that has to be passed, I want sth in GAS directly to put the value in the output_array

Answer (score 0):

After some search and work I came up with a temp sol, 
This will give the calender event of the candidate whom you have added in your calender.
So its basically how to add a user id to the calender of the id who is running the script.

```
var events = user1_cal.getEvents(new Date("October 26, 2014"), new Date("October 28, 2014"));
    for (var i=0; i < events.length; i++)
      {
         var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime()]];
         var row=i+1;
         var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,4);
         range.setValues(details);
      }
     Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);
```

[image]